# Gentelella set nav-sm on start

Tags: css, gentelella

setting nav-sm on body for making sidebar take least real state on any layout , it works on desktop size, but for tablet it does not hide it like nav-md or on phone it does not hide it like nav-md used to. what is the best way to set side-bar menu to take least real state as possible for any screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your body class from "nav-md" to "nav-sm"

So this will be the code:

```
<body class="nav-sm">
//
// your page content
//
</body>
```

You should be aware of classes in all dom element to have a responsive site, not just in body tag.